# Trouble with detetcting where a player clicks

Tags: python, tkinter, click

So I made a simple tracking game as a project, everything about the base works (clicking green squares for +1 point) but when I added a blue square that only sometimes appears it doesnt want to detect it when a player clicks on it.

```
import tkinter
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=500,height=500)
from random import *
canvas.pack()


def timer1():
        canvas.delete("all")
        global cx,cy,rn
        rn = randrange(3)
        cx = randrange(50,300)
        cy = randrange(20,250)
        cw = randrange(50,300)
        cz = randrange(20,250)
        canvas.create_rectangle(cx,cy,cx-size,cy+size,fill="green")
        canvas.create_text(100,10,text="Score: ")
        canvas.create_text(200,10,text=score)
        if rn == 2:
            canvas.create_rectangle(cw,cz,cw-size,cz+size,fill="blue")
        if score < 100 and score > -10:
            canvas.after(1000,timer1)
        elif score == -10:
            canvas.delete("all")
            canvas.create_text(200,100,text="Wow you suck :/")
        else:
            canvas.delete("all")
            canvas.create_text(200,100,text="Good job")
    
    
def click(cor):
    global score
    x = cor.x
    y = cor.y
    if cx > x > cx-size and cy < y < cy+size:
        score = score + 1
    else:
        score = score -1
    if cw > x > cw-size and cz < y < cz+size:
        score = score + 5
canvas.bind("<Button-1>",click)
    
score = 0
cx = 0
cy = 0
cz = 0
cw = 0
rn = 0
size = 50
timer1()
```

Comment: Have you done anything to try to debug this, such as checking the variables inside of `click` to see if they are what you think they should be?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `cw` and `cz` as global variables inside `timer1()` as well.